# FilesMatch in .htaccess file no longer working

Tags: .htaccess

I used to use this code on my old shared hosting, but have switched to a VPS, but it does not seem to work as intended.

```
<FilesMatch "\.(inc|log|exe|sql|ini|conf|bin)$">
 Deny from all
</FilesMatch>
```

I'm trying to block access to these extentions, but if I type in a file that does not exist it still puts 403 forbidden and not 404 not found. Any idea why?

Thank you